# Android permissions manager

Tags: android, open-source, privacy

I want to restrict the permissions of some apps on my **rooted** Android 4.1.2 phone.

Is there an **open source** app for this?

It would let me browse the list of installed apps, I would pick one and uncheck/re-check each permission as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of my favorite topics, so let me list some choices for you. But before I do, I need to point out some "gaps" in your question: not all solutions work on all Android versions:

- **Android 4.3/4.4:** These two versions have built-in permission management (to a degree) – but it is hidden. You can select from a bunch of [AppOps FrontEnds](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_1027) (again, considering your Android version: some only work with 4.3, others only with 4.4) to reveal the interface, and control your app's permissions. AFAIK you cannot restrict network access with them – but I must admit I've never tried those.
- **ROM-specific:** There were two full-fledged permission managers working on CyanogenMod, both being free and open source: [PDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid) and [PDroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.digitalfeed.pdroidalternative). But for both, development seems to have stopped: last releases were 2012 resp. 2013.

But now for the real stuff: I'd recommend taking a look at **[XPrivacy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer)** and **[DonkeyGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.donkeyguard)**. As "real permission/privacy managers" do, both require root – which you stated is no issue. The two additionally require the Xposed Framework to hook into system resources – and I can really recommend that framework for a lot of other things (not part of your question; but take a look at my [Xposed resource collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_xposed) for details).

The requirements you gave are pretty simple, and matched by all of the mentioned apps. But what makes the two last ones so special? For *DonkeyGuard* it's mostly the user-friendlyness and ease of operation: you won't need a big tutorial to use this (but on the con side, it additionally needs the [Cydia Substrate](http://www.appbrain.com/app/cydia-substrate/com.saurik.substrate) for network stuff, which is npt really open source AFAIK) – while *XPrivacy* gives you a flexibility and granularity you find nowhere else: you can e.g. restrict network access, but still allow parts of it – see the 3<sup>rd</sup> screenshot below:

[image: XPrivacy] [image: Symbols] [image: granularity]
<sup>*XPrivacy:* Normal app view, legend of symbols, granularity (click images for larger variants)</sup>

This can of course be overwhelming, and you for sure will need some time to unleash *XPrivacy's* full potential on your device. Plus it comes with a minor restriction: as the name suggests, *XPrivacy* understands itself as *privacy* manager, not permission manager – so it doesn't cover all permissions (but everything privacy relevant – which should cover everything we're usually after). *XPrivacy" is definitely open source: [find the code at Github](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy/).

As I also mentioned *DonkeyGuard:*

[image: DonkeyGuard Applist] [image: Access Warning] [image: Permissions]
<sup>*DonkeyGuard:* App list, Access warning, Permissions (click images for larger variants)</sup>

You will note that *DonkeyGuard* even rates your apps by "possible danger" (the more stars, the more potential danger). While [DonkeyGuard can be found at Github](https://github.com/CollegeDev/DonkeyGuard), I'm not sure about its open-source-ness: the code there only holds its readmes.

Both apps support, additional to your requirements:

- revoke a permission completely (might cause Force-Closes)
- provide "null data" for a permission (e.g. empty address book/calendar)
- provide (random) fake data for a permission (e.g. fake GPS coordinates, IMEI, etc.)
- generally restrict the permission, or only "on demand"

Going by rating and community, you most likely will end up with *Xprivacy* – but you of course have the choice. If you're looking for more choices, take a look at my list of [Permission Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_380)s, and make your own pick :)

Comment: +1 I've been a user of XPrivacy and didn't think that it might be missing some permissions considering its goal. Anyhow, its GitHub page says: [XPrivacy doesn't revoke or block permissions from an application](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#description) while you've written "*revoke a permission completely (might cause Force-Closes)*". What I failed to understand is, when I check a permission in XPrivacy like the check-marks in 3rd screenshot, does it then provide fake data for those permissions or really restrict the app from using them? I know about faking IMEI, and others from Settings.

Comment: @Firelord it's quite a while ago I've tried it last (I'm a long-term LBE user and really loved the "light-weight international version" – which no longer works with JB+) – but I'm about to give it another try soon (the "full version" of LBE is a monster I'm using max 20% of, and it's closed source). So I'm not really sure how which behavior is achieved currently. There're a lot of places allowing for "fake data", almost all allow for "null" (aka "is empty/not available", "flight mode active", whatever). As for your quote: read the sentence following it :)

Comment: I didn't understand the part following the quote. Please consider helping this poor man. It's a query I neither asked to the developer itself nor on any forum or on [android.se] because I was waiting for someone to write on it and I just popup there for my query. :)

Comment: Btw: *XPrivacy* was using parts of Cydia in the past as well, as you can see in some commit messages – e.g. "Remove last remainder of Cydia substrate support" (e4ebb205). // Edit: As for your "query", I'm not sure. Have to check for myself to figure that out.